# Check if my computer has bios password (via VB / C#)

Tags: c#, vb.net, dns, passwords, bios

Im doing a checklist in my domain.
I was wondering if there's a way to obtain the BIOS status of Computer, particularly BIOS Password status,
I want to know if a Computer has BIOS password or not without shutting down.

Comment: This capability is going to be dependent on the type of motherboard. But if you have a common type of motherboard, WMI would be the way to go: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/880e5bc3-ba05-4522-ac17-fd999a26621a/querying-for-bios-password-with-wmi?forum=configmanagerosd

Comment: Yes, they are all DELL machines. the point is, I dont know what exactly is the attribute I need in WMI

Comment: you can read bios setting using using WMI in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/305227/how-to-get-bios-information-in-csharp-desktop-appl but I test it, doesn't contain bios password.

Answer (score 2):

for dell computers its possible to check if there is a password.

```
objInstance.Properties_.Item("Password").Value
```

have a look [here](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/omci-sample-scripts) and [here](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/solutions/omci_info.pdf)